# Having an error with the StartDate and EndDate on SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I am trying to run the code it shows me an error at the line of the Date()? Can someone help me out where is the problem, thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
        ProjectID varchar(50), Name varchar(50),
        MaxHours FLOAT, Date() AS StartDate,
        Date() AS EndDate, DepartmentName varchar(50),
        CONSTRAINT ProjectIDPK PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID),
        CONSTRAINT DepartmentNameFK FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName)
        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I think you mean StartDate Date, EndDate Date (otherwise you are creating two columns with the same name)

Comment: Yes, with StartDate and EndDate. I dont know where the error in the code.

Comment: Replace `Date() as StartDate` with `StartDate Date` and the same for EndDate

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: When I am running this query it shows me : There is already a relationship name DepartmentNameFK in the current database, because I put as Foreign Key in different query too. The code is as follow: CONSTRAINT ProjectIDPK PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID),
CONSTRAINT DepartmentNameFK FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName)
REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE